# Delphi: Sending a string command using Libby's TPipeConsole

Tags: delphi, console, pipe

I'm programming in Delphi XE8  an interface to a chess engine which is a DOS console application. I'm using Libby's TPipeConsole to communicate between the two,

My question is: How to send a string command to the engine using TPipeCosnole.

My code below doesn't work:

```
procedure TForm1.WriteCommand( InText : String );
var
  AnsiBuf : AnsiString;
  dwWrite : DWORD;
begin
  AnsiBuf := AnsiString( InText ) + #13#10;
  PipeConsole1.Write( AnsiBuf, Length( AnsiBuf ) );
end;
```

Comment: I suspect you are using an old version of it.  Have a look at http://francois-piette.blogspot.co.za/2013/04/inter-process-communication-using-pipes.html and the link it points to to download.

Comment: I'm using François Piette updates already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Write method:

```
procedure TPipeConsole.Write(const Buffer; Length : Integer);
```

It uses untyped argument `Buffer`, so you are sending pointer (string address) instead of string body.

Right way:

```
PipeConsole1.Write(PAnsiChar(AnsiBuf)^, Length( AnsiBuf ) );
```